# CPPdepend LCOM metric query

Tags: ndepend, lcom, cppdepend

I was trying to get LCOM metric report using CppDepend. I wrote the following query

```
// <Name>TODO short description</Name>
from  t in Application.Types
select new {t,t.LCOM, t.LCOMHS}
```

But this query gives table value for only header files in the code. It doesn't report the values for Cpp files.

Please help as I am new to doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query give you the LCOM of types ( classes or structs) and not the LCOM of header or source files

[image]

Comment: In my source code, when I select group by Namespaces(Flat Hierarchy or Tree Hierarchy), it shows the files. And all these files were Header files only. That's why I was confused.